# Minimalistic JavaScript sprite manipulation libraries

Tags: javascript, sprites

Are there (or can someone recommend) any minimalistic JavaScript based libraries for sprite(s) manipulation? Preferably DOM oriented.

Comment: Minimalist JavaScript developers don't use libraries.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/what-are-good-js-libraries-for-game-dev-html5

Comment: Any library you use will have slack, to make something minimalistic is to strip it to only the necessary features.  Why not just write a simple sprite class?

Comment: @Adrian Seeley: can you share some resources on this topic please?

Comment: Google is your friend:
http://forrst.com/posts/Javascript_Sprite_Class_animation-0jZ

Answer (score 1):

[EaselJS](http://easeljs.com/) does sprite animation with HTML Canvas if that is something you could use. It's not really minimalistic, but does a really good job of handling sprite sheets.

The source is split across multiple files, so with a bit of work you could probably pull apart just the bits to do sprite animation ([BitmapSequence](http://easeljs.com/docs/BitmapSequence.html)).